# I can not find cylinder Projection panel

Tags: interface

I am working with Blender v2.78 windows 10 64 bit.
I am doing  a course  using UV projections. When I call Mash => UVunwrap => Cylinder Projection I am supposed to find the Cylinder Projection Panel, but it is not there.
need help.
Dov

Answer (score 2):

It comes up at the bottom of the Tool Shelf (press <kbd>T</kbd> if the panel is not visible):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That panel should appear at the bottom of the *Tool Shelf*, or you can open a floating one by pressing <kbd>F6</kbd>. It is only available after you've unwrapped and before doing anything else that affects the mesh.

This is the floating one.

[image]

The tool shelf should be at the left side, and if it isn't there, there should be a small plus sign. You can open the tool shelf by grabbing the plus sign with you mouse, and pulling it away from the edge, or by pressing <kbd>T</kbd>.

[image]

If the *Cylinder Projection* is not at the bottom of the tool shelf, the plus sign should be there, and you can open the panel by grabbing the plus sign and pulling it upwards.

[image]

[image]

Comment: And please don't ask why I used a UV sphere and not a cylinder here, because I don't know. However, it is perfectly possible to unwrap a sphere with cylinder projection, though the texture may look strange.